# Incorrect colouring of Surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, data-analysis

I'm currently trying to create a surface plot of a laser energy output using the following code:

```
Xx_array = np.array(Xx)
X_data_array = np.array(Zx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (14, 6))

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d');
surfX = ax4.plot_surface(Xx_array.T, X_fixed_Y_axis, X_data_array.T,
                         rstride = 1, cstride = 1, antialiased = False,
                         cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0);

fig.colorbar(surfX, shrink=0.5, aspect=4);
```

The only problem is that it does not seem to colour code the plot properly and makes the whole thing red. This is obviously incorrect because I have another plot which contains extremely similar data but colours correctly. I've been through the code carefully to look for discrepancies but none can be found. Is there something I'm missing? The colour coding bar is also not scaled correctly and doesn't follow the expected values nor the actually colour coding of the plot.

Code for the other data that works correctly is as follows:

```
Xy_array = np.array(Xy)
Y_data_array = np.array(Zy)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (14, 6))

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
surfY = ax5.plot_surface(Xy_array.T, Y_fixed_Y_axis, Y_data_array.T, 
                         rstride = 1, cstride = 1, antialiased = False, 
                         cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0);

fig.colorbar(surfY, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 4);
```

I've tried manually setting the data to scale by but this sends the whole plot blue:

```
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.coolwarm)
m.set_array(X_data_array.T)
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: check your `surfX` parameter, that is what is causing the problem if you are saying `colorbar` works with `surfY`

Comment: I have tried it. The plots are virtually identical - surfX is an X-direction laser cross section and surfY is a Y-direction laser cross section. They display almost the same data on the Z-axis, and only have inverted data on the X and Y.